# Of vs among - correct preposition

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the two prepositions is the appropriate one for this sentence?

Personally, I think it's a good thing to have a lot of friends; anyway, it's inevitable that we'll build closer relationships with just a few of them. Finally, **of / among** all your close friends, it's essential that you choose your best friend who should be the person you trust the most.

Comment: equivalent usage here

Answer (score 1):

You can use either **of**, **out of**,  **among** or **from** in your example sentence. They all have essentially the same meaning.

If there is any subtle difference, I would say that **out of** is the "strongest" in terms of emphasizing that your best friend is ranked higher than every other friend in your circle.